# How much bandwidth could you get if you used every wireless communications device in a hemisphere?

Tags: technology, communication

Modern telecommunications systems only use a certain portion of the spectrum, and that portion is then chopped up into smaller sections by frequency. This is why a radio station can have the frequency 107.7 MHz--that portion of the spectrum is allotted to them.

Now, let's say a powerful NGO (think XCOM) needs to wirelessly transmit a massive amount of data to a single target (in my idea, they need to transmit highly-complex calculations to a giant mecha before it can fire its experimental particle accelerator). This amount of data is far beyond the ability of a standard wireless connection to transfer, due to its sheer size.

However, the NGO has strong ties to major world governments and a team of highly-skilled hackers. Thinking quickly, the base commander gets on the phone with the heads of state of every country with satellites within transmitting range of the mecha, while her hackers hijack every radio tower within range and make them transmit pieces of the calculations.

How much data could such a network, comprised of nearly every satellite in the hemisphere and every radio tower in the nation (we'll assume the United State, but any ballpark is fine) transfer?

Put another way, **what is the maximum amount of data humans could transfer wirelessly to a specific location using current technology?**

Comment: I think that any answer that we provide will be superseded shortly.  This technology is rapidly advancing and they're working on things like transmitting different signals on different polarization of the same band.  So take any answer as a ballpark only figure.  Also range plays a very important factor in data transmission speeds.

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble answering this question because the backstory leaves a great deal of questions.  How do you plan on the mecha receiving these signals?  If you need to transmit at a terabyte per second (such as if you could point 6-7 HTS satellites at your mecha without overlaping frequency bands), you need a radio receiver on the mecha that can receive that data.  Also, how long do you think hijacking a satellite takes?  Have you considered whether it could be more effective to sneakernet some harddrives up to the mecha?

Comment: Ever heard of fiber optics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, RF communications do not work in the way you ask.  For one thing, you're going to need a receiver on your mecha that can pull in all of that wideband data.  You're going to have to explain why you have such an astonishingly powerful antenna system without some datalink going home.  Also, you can't simply point everything at your mecha and expect to function without conflict.  Many satellites are operating on the same bands, simply pointed in different directions so that they do not have any interference.

However, we can make some very broad assumptions, pretending all of the realism issues go away.  From [this](https://transition.fcc.gov/oet/tac/tacdocs/meeting92711/Spectrum_Efficiency_Metrics_White_Paper_by_TAC_Sharing_Working_Group_25Sep2011.doc) document from the FCC, they found broadband satellites like those used for satellite TV tended to be able to produce 3.23 bits/s/Hz of communication bandwidth (that number is known as "spectral efficiency").  We can use this to figure out a ballpark theoretical maximum.  At best, we can get about 30GHz of bandwidth for our satellites.  The real limit is the high end of the band.  Once you get much above 30Ghz, you enter millimeter wave radio, which is really not very effective over long distances because it gets attenuated by the atmosphere.  **This suggests a theoretical maximum of 96.9 Gb/s**, if all of the implementation issues all go away.  That's not all that fast, if you have to do some hacking to make it happen.  You can buy an off-the-shelf [gigabit wireless system](http://www.airlinx.com/products.cfm/product/2-26-760.htm), which runs at 1/77th the speed over a 5 mile distance, but requires no up front time to hack the planet.

Comment: "At best, we can get about 30GHz of bandwidth for our satellites. The real limit is the high end of the band." You seem to be including the carrier frequency in the bandwidth; that's not correct.

Comment: @Samuel What do you mean?  As far as I can tell, what I wrote is independent of the idea of carriers.

Comment: Satellites operate in ~6 bands, each with center frequencies between 1-30 GHz, but each only has a bandwidth of 0.001-3 GHz. For instance, the L-band from 1-2Ghz has a bandwidth of just a few megahertz. The actual data rate (for position) is only 50 bits/sec, but in this case you seem to be bringing your own modulation, which could possibly increase that rate.

Comment: @Samuel Oh, I was creating a theoretical maximum.  I ignored the fact that modern satellites don't have access to the *entire* spectrum in a broadband sense, and ignored the individual bands, to point out that even if you ignored all those things, you're still only 77x faster than an off-the-shelf wireless system (and the OP stated the data could not go over a normal wireless system)

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, I suppose I'm just confirming that reality is indeed worse than your best case scenario.

Answer (score 3):

You do not understand how wireless works.

Yes, the router in my house can transmit 52 Gbps and your router in your house can transmit 52 Gbps... because mine is in my house and yours is in yours.

A communication device operates in a given frequency band with a given capacity, add another device to the same frequency and position and what you get is not extra capacity, but interference and **less** capacity.

Your local router works next to your neighbour router because:

1. the EM waves at that frequency are easily stopped by walls, windows, etc.
2. the router can use one of several "bands" or channels (so if one band has interference, the router can be tuned to another band).

So, no, adding electronics does not magically increase bandwidth. In fact, EM spectrum is tightly regulated and in some countries it is auctioned for media companies to buy a share of it from the government.

Additionally, as expressed above, not all of the EM spectrum is equally useful: microwaves and visible light are easily blocked and may work only in a Line-of-Sight basis, gamma rays are difficult to produce and modulate and are harmful for people, some frequencies are stopped by the ionosphere and others are not.

And as for the satellites (and all of the question in general) you are ignoring completely several important facts:

1. the issue of latency (generally known as "ping"). Data connections through satellites are very slow, they work well for TV because the communication is unidirectional (only the TV station sends, it waits for no answer). If you use it for voice calls, you begin to notice that, after you stop speaking, the people on the line needs a small time (about 1s) to listen the data that is still "in the line". So, if your superweapon sends a message back to control center telling that it is beginning to overheat, by the time a reply with the adequate orders returns, the superweapon will have vaporized.
2. Antenna. Most of the EM spectrum is absorbed to a degree by the atmosphere, the exception being long wave frequencies which do not support a lot of bandwith. So you will need a quite powerful and big antenna in your mecha to connect to the satellite, and a way to keep it aligned even while the mecha is moving.

Comment: I know that adding more machines that transmit on the same frequency won't help; what I want to know is how much bandwidth we could get if we used all the frequencies we could.

The NGO is commandeering all the parts of the spectrum normally reserved for radio and other wireless comms.

As for the latency, the calibrations are a one-time thing; the gun needs the data to align its subsystems, but after that it can fire.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of fundamental issues with your question.

- The most commonly used forms of radio just do not go very far, 100 km at most in optimal conditions.
- Those that go further are much more interferenced by weather.
- Why would a giant mecha require external calculations on that scale? Any organization that has the funds to make a giant mecha could easily have the calculating machine built in.
- Redirecting a satellite to send such signals is not easily done on short notice.
- Calculations are usually not something that you can do and transmit in parallel or even in the wrong order.
- I am not aware of any calculations an experimental superweapon would need beyond "where do I aim?", and such a calculation would usually just give a result like "Aim X degrees to the left or right, 2 degrees skywards and with a force of X".
- Such calculations as mentioned above are trivial for current computers. Hell, they were doing them 500 years ago manually using smooth bore cannons. Modern artillery can do these calculations faster than the gun can reload.

Comment: The weapon in question is an exotic particle accelerator that was rushed out the lab before it was finished. The calculations needed are not targeting calculations, but calibrations of ultra-complex electromagnetic fields and data needed to stop the weapon from tearing itself apart. The data was supposed to be calculated in the lab, but they had no time to finish.
The only computer fast enough to finish the calculations in time is an immobile quantum supercomputer in a bunker. The computer is irreplaceable and too valuable to install in a mecha, even if it would fit.